# How to run an nginx container as non root?

Tags: linux, docker, nginx, permissions, containers

Every time I try to run the container as non root, I get the following error:

```
 the "user" directive makes sense only if the master process runs with super-user privileges, ignored in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:2
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM nginx:1.17.6
RUN chown -R nginx:nginx /var/cache/nginx && \
        chown -R nginx:nginx /var/log/nginx && \
        chown -R nginx:nginx /etc/nginx/conf.d
RUN chmod -R 777 /etc/nginx/conf.d

USER nginx

COPY app/build /usr/share/nginx/html

RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

COPY nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d


CMD ["nginx","-g","daemon off;"]
```

Answer (score 26):

Use the rootless docker-imager from nginx.

**Image**

```
nginxinc/nginx-unprivileged
```

**DockerHub**
https://hub.docker.com/r/nginxinc/nginx-unprivileged

**GitHub**
https://github.com/nginxinc/docker-nginx-unprivileged

Comment: I don't know why, but nginx has two official repos. The unprivileged image on GitHub was posted by the official nginx-GitHub.

Comment: how can i change the default nginx user to my own user? I can't do addgroup or adduser on top of this?

Comment: You can do it in the Dockerfile with the [USER-keyword](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#user).

Comment: it throws an error saying only root can add another user. sudo doesn't work and su asks for password

Comment: Open a new question, then I can give you an example. :)

Comment: This image has thorws up erros during trivy analysis, is there any alternative?

Comment: Perhaps you want to open a new question about the errors. An alternative: Build an image yourself like Michée describes in his answer.

Answer (score 15):

You can remove (or comment) the `user` directive at the top of your `nginx.conf` file.

This directive is relevant when you run nginx as `root`. It defines the user possessing the pid of your nginx subprocesses.

When you don't run nginx as `root` this directive is irrelevant, your nginx subprocesses run with your current user.

Answer (score 4):

try to add this

```
RUN mkdir -p /var/cache/nginx && chown -R ${USER}:${GROUP} /var/cache/nginx && \
    mkdir -p /var/log/nginx  && chown -R ${USER}:${GROUP} /var/log/nginx && \
    mkdir -p /var/lib/nginx  && chown -R ${USER}:${GROUP} /var/lib/nginx && \
    touch /run/nginx.pid && chown -R ${USER}:${GROUP} /run/nginx.pid && \
    mkdir -p /etc/nginx/templates /etc/nginx/ssl/certs && \
    chown -R ${USER}:${GROUP} /etc/nginx && \
    chmod -R 777 /etc/nginx/conf.d

# disable nginx user cuz running as non-root
RUN sed -i 's/user nginx;/#user nginx;/g' /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

USER ${USER}

EXPOSE 80 443

CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```