# Docker build for varying architectures with same base image not working

Tags: docker

In my system, I need to create a large number of images for different devices with different architectures. For this, I have a pipeline that creates multiple images using Docker in Docker, all based on one Python:3.8 image, but for different architectures.
In the Docker file, I specify the base image in general:

```
FROM python:3.8
```

In the build command, I specify the architecture of the particular device:

```
docker build --platform linux/arm/v7 --force-rm -t localhost:5000/ImageNameA

docker build --platform linux/amd64 --force-rm -t localhost:5000/ImageNameB
```

The problem I'm facing at the moment is that the Docker host gets confused with the intermediate images when the pipeline triggers both builds at the same time. Docker doesn't seem to be able to store intermediate images for different architectures because they only differ in digest and identical tags are overwritten. For this reason, docker only seems to select the intermediate image by the name and tag and not by the sha265: that matches the architecture. This results in the following error:

```
failed to get destination image "sha256:4d470a81cd7a4eb2a886d8d6ca7848d66f711ea2d44375f4ab10a97c42c1adf3": image with reference sha256: 4d470a81cd7a4eb2a886d8d6ca7848d66f711ea2d44375f4ab10a97c42c1adf3 was found but does not match the specified platform: wanted linux/arm/v7, actual: linux/amd64
```

Also the --force-rm option in the build command does not work here, because the deletion is done after the build process is finished.
I also don't want to declare the images with @sha in the dockerfile, because the identical code should be used on different devices.

What is the best way to work around or solve this problem?

Comment: Have you tried using different tags? `name:arm7` and `name:amd64` etc?

Comment: Im not sure if i can, because the Pyhton container is an intermediate container that is automatically pulled.

Comment: I think @SoftwareEngineer thought about naming your images differently for different types of architecture, i.e., `docker build --platform linux/arm/v7 --force-rm -t localhost:5000/ImageName:arm7` and `docker build --platform linux/arm/v7 --force-rm -t localhost:5000/ImageName:amd64`.

Comment: Also, are you aware of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59365141/pushing-images-to-docker-hub-for-multiple-architectures-e-g-amd64-arm64-and?rq=1 -- I don't think it's a duplicate, just something you need to understand

Comment: The Images are actually named by the device-ip. So they are different. It was just not clear in the question. The problem I have are the intermediate images where I am not able to manage them.

Comment: Well, would you share the entire setup then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to solve this problem for me was to include the digest of the Python image in the dockerfile:

AMD64:

```
FROM python:3.8@sha256:7a9aaef601387a8d5ae320243a8295412e43f9a2ca6d36594d3489418b44417a
```

or ARM/V7:

```
FROM python:3.8@sha256:45fbccbc4681e8d9ef517d43f9d0eb8f17b2beac00b0f9697bbf85354ae8a266
```

In this case, the Dockerfile is not general-purpose, but you can create images with the same base image for different platforms simultaneously on the same host.

Comment: This was the solution, I was trying to use Ubuntu as a base image to build an ARM version of my application, it was pulling the amd64 version. It's easy to find the arm64 digest of the Ubuntu image from Dockerhub. Further more you can pass the SHA256 digest in as a --build-arg and therefore build the correct version platform dependant.

Answer (score 2):

You saved me a lot of time.
In my case was using node and nginx as base:

Just needed to add the platform (amd64):

```
FROM amd64/node:16-alpine 
FROM amd64/nginx:latest
```

Comment: Nginx didn't work for me anymore ([error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63108119/how-to-run-an-nginx-container-as-non-root)). so i changed my image to nginxinc/nginx-unprivileged. To change the platform here i used: **FROM --platform=linux/amd64 nginxinc/nginx-unprivileged**